# excel: get index of current chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I create a new chart with

```
Sheets("DatenFilledChart").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlArea
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("DatenFilledChart!$B$4:$B$1004")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=DatenFilledChart!$A$4:$A$1004"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=DatenFilledChart!$B$1"
```

In order to work with the current chart I want to save its index with

```
indexOfChart = ActiveChart.Index
```

That however fails with

> The method Index is invalid for a object _Chart

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this:

```
indexOfChart = Shapes.Count
```

instead of

```
indexOfChart = ActiveChart.Index
```

`Index` property is not applicable for Charts collection:

> **Index Property**
>
> The position of a **Tab** object within a **Tabs** collection or a **Page** object
>   in a **Pages** collection.

Read more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194426.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Index is a property of the ChartObject class.

Chart is a member of the ChartObject class.

Therefore, when you use a Chart object, you have to go up a level in the heirarchy like so:

```
indexOfChart = ActiveChart.Parent.Index
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `AddChart` returns a reference to the added object, the easiest way is just to work with that reference...

```
Sub tester()
    Dim co As Shape

    Set co = Sheet1.Shapes.AddChart()
    With co.Chart
        .ChartType = xlArea
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$B$5")
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Testing"
        'etc etc
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code with the enhancement of setting `Sheet1` to a variable: `
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("DatenFilledChart")
ShapeRef = ws.Shapes.AddChart()` but that fails with error 91: variable not defined.

Comment: Make sure you have declared `ShapeRef`, and use `Set` when you assign it.